# How to keep a user logged on

Tags: python, session, kivy

How do apps like instagram, twitter etc. Know a user is logged on and when next the user starts the app, the user doesn't have to input their credentials all over. Is it by writing and reading from a file, if  yes, doesn't it mean a user can find the file that the app reads from, alter it's content and change who's logged on to someone else without authentication

Comment: sharedPreference, token, a refresh token and the token's lifetime, session less REST api calls. What is your question?

Comment: We can not explain as aspects of client authentication and sessions here. Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Save their token in `LocalStorage` for web front-end, for other platform 
   you can save in somewhere that can storage.
2. Token-Based api. (access with token with any resource)